# Are there maximum entropy distributions with fixed moments of a certain order?

Tags: moments, exponential-family, maximum-entropy

A characterization of the multivariate Gaussian distribution with a fixed mean and covariance matrix is that it is the unique probability distribution that maximizes differential entropy. That is, the Gaussian PDF is the unique solution to the following maximization problem:
$$
\text{argmax} \{\mathbb{E}_f[\log(f(x))] : \mathbb{E}_f[x_i] = \mu_i,\; \mathbb{E}_f[x_i x_j] = \sigma_{ij}\}.
$$
When there is a solution to this problem if we specify the moments of degree at most $k$ to the probability distribution? That is, when is there a solution to the problem

$$
\text{argmax} \{\mathbb{E}[\log(f(x))] : \forall \alpha,\; \mathbb{E}_f[x^{\alpha}] = \mu_{\alpha}\}.
$$

Here, $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ ranges over those values where $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \le k$.

For example, it is obviously necessary that there exists a probability distribution with these given moments for there to be a solution (I've heard the question of whether or not there exists such a probability distribution is referred to as a moment problem in some contexts). Is this sufficient? Has this particular family of probability distributions been referred to in the literature before?